# 3D visualization of .dicom files with ipyvolume

Tags: python, pydicom, medical-imaging

i'm trying to visualize a set of `.dicom` files using `pydicom` and `ipyvolume`.

I used `pydicom` to read files and then sorted them by their location and turned the slices into a 3D array. I could draw a 3D model of the data using `ipyvolume.pylab.plot_isosurface()` although I'm not sure if this is the right way of visualizing medical images (it's all solid pixels with the same opacity and color). I've also tried `ipyvolume.pylab.volshow()` but that did not work.

Is there a right way to visualize medical images with `ipyvolume`? or this is just not the right library for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used ipyvolume, but looking at the documentation it ought to be able to visualize DICOM image sets.

If you want to try another package, I use SimpleITK to load DICOM images and itkwidgets do volume visualization in a Jupyter notebook.

Here's a simple notebook that load a DICOM series and displays it:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import itkwidgets

# Get the DICOM file names in the current directory
names = sitk.ImageSeriesReader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames('.')

# Read the DICOM series
reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
reader.SetFileNames(names)
img = reader.Execute()

itkwidgets.view(img)
```

If the directory has more than one DICOM series in it, GetGDCMSeriesFileNames has a seriesID parameter you can give it to specify which series to load.

Answer (score 2):

DICOM file does not have 'voxel' data so you can't simply plot a dicom in 3D view. You should estimate voxel data using slices of a dicom series. after that, using a 3D modeling algorithm such as Marching Cubes you can extract final 3D model. Take a look at [CTU](https://github.com/a-m-farahani/CTU).